# Save/cancel prompt before closing modal (when modal has been closed by ESC/ click-backdrop)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

When manually closing the modal, there is no problem. I simply create some prompt, and only when the prompt (sweetalert) is closed, i call the BsModalRef.hide() method.

Now when the modal is being closed by bootstrap-built-in ESC-key and click-outside events, i can still subscribe to the BsModalService.onHide-event. But I dont know how to prevent the modal from actually closing as long as the prompt has not been answered.
    bsModalRef: BsModalRef;

```
constructor(injector: Injector,
            public bsModalService: BsModalService) {
    super(injector);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bsModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(SomeFormComponent,
        {
            keyboard: true,
            backdrop: true
        });

    this.bsModalService.onHide.subscribe((e) => {
        // PROBLEM: modal has already closed here...
        swal({
            text: 'u wanna save changes?',
            title: 'prompt',
            icon: 'warning'
        }).open().then((answer: ModalResult) => {
            switch(answer) {
                case ModalResult.Save:
                    // i would like to save and close modal afterwards
                    break;
                case ModalResult.DontSave:
                    // close modal
                    break;
                default:
                    // stay on modal
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: From a UX point of view. I wonder if you need to promt? If an user press Cancel/Close, why would they want to Save? It is not why we have the first level Buttons: Save or Close? I you take it further, when pressing Save, would not the same logic demand another promt: 'Are you sure you dont want to Cancel?'

Comment: The prompt is really needed: Imagine you entered basic personal data in this modal.  Then you click somewhere outside the modal (this is basically what 'backdrop: true' does....) => modal is closed and your inputs are gone immediately.

Comment: You could place the form in body. You could create a route to a page ex: MyNewPersonalData. That you can route to. By other words avoid using the first dialog. Then you could use your promt as the only dialog. Using dialogs only for special questions is easier for end user.

Comment: Yes, from a UX point of view, its probably better to only have one 'dialog'... unfortunately, we decided for this approach.

Comment: Ok. But until next time. Another important benefit is if the form is in a routing page one can also easy access the form through a link anywhere in the whole app. Without any extra coding as in a modal. Thanks for the talk and hope you solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with ngx-bootstrap you dont have such an Event.

I solved the issue by using the @ng-bootstrap instead of ngx-bootstrap package. For that I also had to upgrade from bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 4 stylesheets.

After that, I can make use of the beforeDismiss-Event.

Thanks for the inputs

Answer (score 0):

I believe by Bs you mean bootstrap and it has a beforeDismiss Event. Try that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Thats correct. I work with ngx-bootstrap 5.1.2. But from what I understand, only the 'old' ng-bootstrap has the beforeDismiss property in the ModalOptions?